# Scala recursive Case class reduction

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a case class like this:

```
case class Test(i: Int, t: Option[Test])
```

I would now like to reduce this case class and add all the i's. So for example., if I have an input like this

```
val x = Test(1, Some(Test(2, Some(Test(3,None)))))
```

I expect the result to be 6 and here is what I have tried so far:

```
def all(acc: Int, test: Test): Int = { 
  if (test.t.isDefined) 
    all(acc, test.t.get)
  else 
    acc + test.i
}
```

This gives me 3 and I see that I'm missing a minor detail somewhere in the recursion and I'm not able to see where! Any clues?

Comment: You are not summing when recursing, plus you are not returning the accumulator.

Comment: Could you elaborate that? Even after doing it, I still get 3!

Comment: In the recursive call you also need to add `i` to `acc` : `all(acc + test.i, test.t.get)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
def sum(acc: Int, test: Test): Int = {
  test.t match {
    case Some(x) => sum(acc + test.i, x)
    case None => acc + test.i
  }
}
```

And a version without accumulator:

```
def sum(test: Test): Int = {
  test.t match {
    case Some(x) => test.i + sum(x)
    case None => test.i
  }
}
```